# SQL SUM repeats for every entry even with group by

Tags: sql

I can't seem to figure out a simple SUM() scenario using group by.

### I am trying to compare a billed total vs paid total from two different tables. What I currently have is:

```
SELECT  
  claimamount,
  SUM(billing_entries.paidamount)
FROM customers.billing_entries, customers.claim_items
WHERE
    lastclaimid = 2132206 
    AND billing_entries.lastclaimid = claim_items.claimid
GROUP BY  claimid, claimamount;
```

---

For this specific case the claimamount is 256.45 and the total paid is 244.44

When I run this I get the following:

```
256.4500 ; 977.7600
```

There are 4 entries in the claim and it is SUMs them each time and returns 4 * the actual sum of them 244.44.

Sample data for the two tables I pull them from:

claim_items:
claimid = 2132206
claimamount = 256.45

billing_entries:

entryId(1)
27136421
paidamount(1)
25.64

entryId(2)
27136423
paidamount(2)
102.5800

entryId(3)
26803842
paidamount(3)
102.5800

entryId(4)
26803839
paidamount(4)
13.64

they all have the same lastclaimid of 2132206

Here are some screenshots of the data

[image: claim_items]

[image: billing_entries]

billingentrygroupid | claimamount | claimid | clientid | entryamount | entryquantity | entryunit | entryunitrate | id       | linenumber | organizationid | procedurecode | receivedon          | renderingprovidercontactid | renderingproviderid | renderingproviderotherid | senton
--------------------+-------------+---------+----------+-------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------
           24015783 |      256.45 | 2132206 |   174491 |      102.58 |          4.00 | UN        |         51.29 | 12483241 |          2 |         168717 | 0365T         | 2017-10-17 16:49:47 |                     370211 |                     | 622843915                | 2017-10-06 18:58:57
           24302220 |      256.45 | 2132206 |   174491 |       25.65 |          1.00 | UN        |         51.29 | 12483242 |          3 |         168717 | 0364T         | 2017-10-17 16:49:47 |                     370211 |                     | 622843915                | 2017-10-06 18:58:57
           24302220 |      256.45 | 2132206 |   174491 |      102.58 |          4.00 | UN        |         51.29 | 12483243 |          4 |         168717 | 0365T         | 2017-10-17 16:49:47 |                     370211 |                     | 622843915                | 2017-10-06 18:58:57
           24015783 |      256.45 | 2132206 |   174491 |       25.65 |          1.00 | UN        |         51.29 | 12483244 |          1 |         168717 | 0364T         | 2017-10-17 16:49:47 |                     370211 |                     | 622843915                | 2017-10-06 18:58:57

Comment: to clarify; it currently SUMs the paid total for each line in the claim, for each line in the claim. So rather than returning the SUM of the 4 lines once, it returns the SUM for each item 4 times.

Comment: why is 'claimid' in group by but not in select?

Comment: remove claimid from the group by clause. Group by clause should contain columns used in  the select clause excluding the aggregated columns.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the code to just get the bare minnimum to try and understand where it was going wrong. If i SELECT it, it shows me the correct claimid but still the wrong SUM.

I group by the claimID because I need to SUM the paid amount for every line that has the associated claimID

Comment: Grouping by claimID makes sense to me. Claimamount is odd. Usually amounts are summed in aggregates

Comment: update your question and add  the related  data sample

Comment: yes,data sample would help a lot to understand your requirement.

Comment: added all the data I am looking at,  the reason I am looking at claimamount instead of SUMing the billed amount is because sometimes the claimamounts are different due to edits being made within them and I am looking for a more accurate comparison

Comment: Using your query and the data you posted I get `256.45` and `244.44`.  So what is the problem again?

Comment: The query always results in 977.76 ; 4 * SUM. everyone else seems to be getting the correct info so I am not sure where the error is.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language (and SQL Workbench/J is a DBMS independent client tool), not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please post sample data as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). With SQL Workbench you can right click in the result choose "Copy to clipboard" and then use the option "Format text" to get a tabular ASCII display.

Comment: Your joins are incomplete.  I can see at least one field that is present in both tables that you are not using but probably should be : `claim_items.billinggroupid = billing_entries.groupid`  There is also likely another field you should be using so that you can join one record from `claim_items` to one *(and only one)* record in `billing_entries` *(possibly `linenumber`, possibly some other field that you haven't shown us)*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but try grouping the amounts paid in a subquery:

```
select
    claimid, claimamount, sum_paid 
from
    customers.claim_items c inner join
    (select
        lastclaimid,
        sum(paidamount) as sum_paid
    from
        customers.billing_entries
    group by
        lastclaimid) p on
    c.claimid = p.lastclaimid
```

Comment: Indeed.  If the data has the same `claim_id` in four rows of `claim_items` and also in four rows of `billing_entries` it is crucial that one or both tables are aggregated before they are joined together.

Answer (score 0):

Using your query and I myself created the query

```
Select  
  ci.claimamount,
  sum(be.paidamount)
from 
   customers.billing_entries be 
   inner join (select distinct(claimid), claimamount from customers.claim_items) as ci 
      on be.lastclaimid = ci.claimid
      and be.lastclaimid = 2132206 
group by ci.claimamount;
```

I am getting the correct data as ouptut i.e claimamount 256.45 and total paidamount as 244.44.
Edit -- Updated Answer according to the screenshots of table provided.

Comment: Still gives me 977.76 as the SUM; not sure where it goes wrong. I can select each billing line and payment and it shows the correct 4 lines with the correct payments on each but SUM adds the SUM for each of the lines and gives me 4 * what I am looking for

Comment: @user8973106 can you please share the screenshot of your 2 tables, you might be skipping something important.

Comment: I added the screenshot for the claim_items table ; It still gives me the wrong sum when I use DISTINCT - I was unaware there were 4 rows in the table.

Comment: @user8973106 I have updated the answer according to the screenshots you provided. Now it will work fine.